# emailing from israel to diaspora isru chag

Tags: halacha

Is it permitted to send an email from Israel on isru chag to a non-religious Jew in the diaspora, whereby he will probably read it on 2nd day yom tov?

Comment: related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/29369/2091

Comment: @Lee Duplicate, i think. (Flagged as such.)

Comment: @Scimonster The other post doesn't yet have a great answer, and there are some (admittedly possibly superficial) differences. With those two factors combined, I'd favor leaving this open for now.

Comment: In addition to Isaac's comment, this question concerns *Yom Tov Sheni* (Mi'DeRabbanan) whereas the question I referenced concerns Shabbat (Mi'DeOra'ita).