# Sending emails to people who will read/answer them on shabbat

Tags: halacha, shabbat, internet, lifnei-iver, mail

Is it permissible to send an e-mail on Friday afternoon, knowing it will be answered or at least read on shabbat by a Jew?
I am inclined to think that, since the alternative to someone reading/answering my e-mail on shabbat is other internet browsing at least and deorita melachot at worst, it would be ok (assuming they don't go and do melachot deorita as a consequence of the senders e-mail).

Sources would be well appreciated.

I know there is [a similar question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/29369/bt-emailing-non-observant-family), but it is about sending the e-mail while it's already shabbat for the recipient.

Comment: What do you mean by "I am trying to be more specific"? You think this is not a dupe?

Comment: @DoubleAA the other asks about sending on the recipient's _shabas_; this asks about sending before the recipient's _shabas_.

Comment: אע"פ שמותר לשלוח במוצאי שבת פקס לחו"ל אפילו שעדיין שם שבת וכן ביו"ט שני של גלויות (שבארץ ישראל הוא אסרו חג) מכל מקום יש להחמיר בכך משום לפני עיור לא תיתן מכשול

Comment: I question the basic assumption of the question.  An email is not the same as a phone call.  With a phone call, there is the expectation it will be answered immediately, but with an email, there is no expectation it will be answered immediately.  Just because an email is sent just prior to shabbos does not mean it will be received, read, or responded to on shabbos.

Comment: -DoubleAA I am trying to understand how worried we must be about causing non observant Jews to preform derabanans.
@HachamGabriel המביא דבר בשם אומרו... thanks.
-Dennis that is incorrect, I am speaking here of a work related matter where people, at least in my field, tend to answer promptly, and it is therefor a valid assumption.

Comment: @YaakovPinsky Sefer Shabbat Kahalacha.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11839/can-i-cause-a-melacha-to-happen-in-a-place-where-shabbat-has-already-started/