# Is it permitted for an Israeli to use Mi Yodeya on motzei shabbat?

Tags: halacha, motzei-shabbos, stackexchange, lifnei-iver, time-zone

Is it permitted for an Israeli to use Mi Yodeya on motzei shabbat? Would this be *lifnei iver* (placing an obstacle in front of a fellow Jew) in encouraging non-shabbat observant Jews to click/vote/respond to a question/answer?

The question assumes that many (a  majority of?) MY users are based in the US where it is still shabbat for 5-8  hours while already motzei shabbat in Israel. I wonder if the fact it is shabbat for a majority would make a *halachic* difference vs. a situation where there might possibly be someone on the Internet using MY on their shabbat but the majority wouldn't be *mechalel* Shabbat.

Would the answer be different for the second day of yom tov which is *chol/chol hamoed* in Israel?

Comment: related but not answering the question (others focus on sending faxes, i.e., causing work where it is shabbat, I want to know about possibly encouraging people to do a melacha they wouldn't have done otherwise) https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/30711/sending-emails-to-people-who-will-read-answer-them-on-shabbat https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/29369/bt-emailing-non-observant-family-on-friday-afternoon https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11839/can-i-cause-a-melacha-to-happen-in-a-place-where-shabbat-has-already-started/

Comment: I often visit and sometimes post on Motzash here but have never thought of this concern. +1

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/2671/1713

Comment: Considering that it's a given that anyone may post, and there is no guarantee that any specific poster is a) Jewish and b) in a specific time zone (even if they are "from" there), I don't see this being an issue. Otherwise a non-Jew eating in a non-kosher restaurant would ALSO be *lifnei iver,* since an observe *could* assume they were Jewish. Or someone buying chometz on the last day of pesach (such as from a kosher Dunkin Donuts).

Comment: relevant comment from @ShmuelBrin (found it by coincidence) http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/428/11501

Comment: @mbloch You should ask a rov or posek - this isn't the place to get definitive halachic rulings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*This is a very good and interesting question*. On the outset we can eliminate the possibility of "lifnei Iver" in this case. The problem of Lifney Iver is if you are the person that permits the Avera. 
**Tosfoth Avoda Zara 6B**:

> מנין שלא יושיט אדם כוס יין לנזיר. נראה דה''ה בכל שאר איסורין אלא להכי נקט כוס יין לנזיר משום דמסתמא למישתי **קא בעי ליה כיון דכ''ע חמרא שתו ושמא שכח נזירתו אבל ישראל שאמר הושיט לי נבלה או חזיר או שום איסור אין לחושדו מלהושיט לו אבל אם ידוע לו שרוצה לאכלו אסור להושיט לו** ואפי' הוא שלו מדקאמר אי לא יהיב ליה שקיל ליה איהו ולפי זה אסור להושיט למומרים לעבודת כוכבים דבר איסור אע''פ שהוא שלהם כי הדבר ידוע שיאכלוהו והוא נאסר להם דכישראל גמור חשבינן ליה ומיירי בדקאי במקום שלא יוכל ליקח אם לא יושיט לו זה וכדמסיק דקאי בתרי עברי נהרא

According to the Tosfoth, if the Chilul Shabboth is not a habitual action, there is no lifnei Iver. I learn from the example of Tossfoth: Handing a slice of Issur [such as non-kosher food] to a practicing Jew is not called a priori Lifney Iver.
The **Smag** (Lavim 168) by following the same reasoning says:

> והוא הדין דאסור להושיט דבר איסור למשומדים כענין זה
>   (to give a slice of Issur to a "meshumad" (that regarding the problem here is the equivalent of a non-practicing Jew) is prohibited due to Lifney Iver).

I guess it can happen with some of our friends. But we will look at several scenarios below with the aid of the Tosfoth in Massecheth Sabbath. Lets begin from the Shulchan Aruch.

**Shulchan Aruch Orach Chayim** 347 Saif 1:

> מִן הַתּוֹרָה אֵינוֹ חַיָּב אֶלָּא כְּשֶׁעוֹקֵר חֵפֶץ מֵרְשׁוּת הַיָּחִיד וּמַנִּיחוֹ בִּרְשׁוּת הָרַבִּים, אוֹ אִיפְּכָא, אֲבָל פָּשַׁט יָדוֹ לְפָנִים, וְחֵפֶץ בְּיָדוֹ, וּנְטָלוֹ חֲבֵרוֹ הָעוֹמֵד בִּפְנִים, אוֹ שֶׁפָּשַׁט יָדוֹ לַחוּץ וְחֵפֶץ בְּיָדוֹ וּנְטָלוֹ חֲבֵרוֹ הָעוֹמֵד בַּחוּץ, שֶׁזֶּה עָקַר וְזֶה הִנִּיחַ, שְׁנֵיהֶם פְּטוּרִים אֲבָל אָסוּר לַעֲשׂוֹת כֵּן מִדְּרַבָּנָן. וְאִם פָּשַׁט יָדוֹ לְפָנִים וְחֵפֶץ בְּיָדוֹ וְהִנִּיחוֹ לְתוֹךְ יַד חֲבֵרוֹ הָעוֹמֵד בִּפְנִים, אוֹ שֶׁפָּשַׁט יָדוֹ לְפָנִים וְנָטַל חֵפֶץ מִתּוֹךְ יַד חֲבֵרוֹ הָעוֹמֵד בִּפְנִים וְהוֹצִיאוֹ לַחוּץ, שֶׁנִּמְצָא שֶׁהָעוֹמֵד בַּחוּץ לְבַדּוֹ עָקַר וְהִנִּיחַ, הוּא חַיָּב וַחֲבֵרוֹ פָּטוּר אֲבָל אָסוּר, וַאֲפִלּוּ אִם הָעוֹמֵד בַּחוּץ הוּא עַכּוּ''ם, אָסוּר מִפְּנֵי שֶׁהוּא כְּנוֹתְנוֹ עַל מְנַת לְהוֹצִיא. וְהוּא הַדִּין לְהוֹצִיא יָדוֹ לַחוּץ וְהִנִּיחוֹ בְּיַד חֲבֵרוֹ הָעוֹמֵד בַּחוּץ, אוֹ שֶׁנָּטַל מִיַּד חֲבֵרוֹ הָעוֹמֵד בַּחוּץ, וְהִכְנִיס בִּפְנִים, שֶׁהָעוֹמֵד בִּפְנִים חַיָּב שֶׁהוּא עָקַר, וְהָעוֹמֵד בַּחוּץ פָּטוּר אֲבָל אָסוּר

*We see a case directly related to the question asked.*: A beggar reaches his hand inside a house, and the owner offers him a loaf of bread, which the poor man lifts and removes. Only the poor does "Hotsaa" but the man who is in the house also violates a ban. Which? Says the **Magen Avraham** SK 4 (his source is the first **Tosfot massecheth Shabbath 3A**): Lifne Iver.

Let us try to read this Tossfoth

It addresses several cases and several degrees of fault. Trying to present him step by step.

> וא''ת והא קא עבר אלפני עור לא תתן מכשול ואפילו מיירי שהיה יכול ליטלו אפילו לא היה בידו דלא עבר משום לפני עור דמושיט כוס יין לנזיר מוקי לה בפ''ק דמס' עבודת כוכבים (דף ו:) דקאי בתרי עברי דנהרא

If the poor man can lift and remove the bread only thanks to the proximity of the outstretched hand, otherwise it could not reach the interior of the house. We have the paradigmatic situation of Lifney Iver. But if the access to the house is comfortable and the poor man can take the bread without anyone's help...

> מ''מ איסור דרבנן מיהא איכא שחייב להפרישו מאיסור

...The owner, however, violated a rabbinic ban. This is the prohibition to hold its next remote from the prohibitions.

> ואפילו אי מיירי בנכרי דלא שייך לפני עור מיהו איסור דרבנן מיהא איכא כדתניא בשילהי פירקין (דף יט.) נותנין מזונות לנכרי בחצר נטלו ויצא אין נזקקין לו משמע דווקא כשהנכרי בחצר אבל אם עומד בחוץ ופושט ידו לפנים משמע דאסור ליתן להדיא ע''מ להוציא 
>  ויש לומר דמיירי בנכרי והחפץ של נכרי דאפילו מכניס ומוציא כל היום אין כאן איסור כלל כיון שאין החפץ של בעל הבית

Tossfoth deducted from a Gemara that a ban is the same when the poor man is a non-Jew, although we do not encourage to make a mistake because there is no Sabbath for him. If the object that the non-Jew moves belongs to the Jewish there is a problem. Otherwise, it's enabled (The purpose of Tossfoth is to find a case where the poor man makes hotsaa or hachnassa with the help of the owner and it is permitted lechatechilla. That is the case of the non-Jew poor man with his own object)

### The response: no it is not lifney Iver DeOrayta. But perhaps a problem of Leafrushey meyissura<sup>[1]</sup>.

---

[1] If you write in Motsach a message for an american friend (a Jew) that is able to open the mail  : "@PlonyAlmoni ...", and He see that an unread message is here, it may be a problem of leafrushe miissura.

Comment: What does "Trying to present him with alineats." mean? I'm not familiar with the word and couldn't find it on Google.

Comment: @Scimonster. It is a bad expression to say step by step