# Can I text a non-observant Jew when it is still Shabbos for them?

Tags: shabbat, melacha-creative-work, time-zone

Can I text a non-observant Jew living in a different time zone, when it is still Shabbos for them? I know there is a high likelihood he will read the text on Shabbos and reply - is there any halachic issue for me to send it and communicate with him?

Comment: At the very least, you would likely be transgressing "lifnei iver" - placing a stumbling block before a blind person- due to the fact that your text is leading him to desecrate the Shabbos by reading it.

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/68699/170 https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/29369/170