# Sending an email or whatsapp to someone when it is shabbos in their location

Tags: shabbat, technology

I have heard that there is some sort of issue with sending messages to people who are in a place where it is shabbos, even if they are totally shomer shabbos. No source comes to mind, but I think it might be the opinion of Rav Schachter.
What would the problem be?

Comment: related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/30711/759

Comment: possible dupe https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/11839/759

Comment: Lifnei Iveir? It's a machlokes I believe whether they must "trip" on your "stumbling block" for you to be in violation. Therefore, according to the opinion that you don't, you would be enabling them, and the fact that they don't read the email doesn't make a difference.

Comment: "What would the problem be?" Could be that because **you** perform a Melacha (where it's Shabbos). Kind of like Issue Gavra/Cheftza.

Comment: @ShmuelBrin Not a dupe. That is "can I do an action that, where I am, is permitted, but where the action occurs, is prohibited?" This is "can I do an action that could possibly tempt someone to do something forbidden, when, were I tempted with that same action, I would be permitted to do it?" Two completely different questions.