# Doing business live with a non-Jew who is in a time zone where Shabbat already arrived

Tags: halacha, shabbat, gentiles, business, time-zone

Is it permitted for a Jew to communicate in real time, conducting business, with a non-Jew who is in a time zone where Shabbat has already arrived, assuming it's not yet Shabbat where the Jew is? Assume that this would entail both parties' performance of melachot during the communication, and requests from the Jew to the non-Jew to do further melachot immediately after the communication.

I know there's a general rule against asking a non-Jew to perform melachot on Shabbat, and another rule against benefiting from melachot he does for a Jew on Shabbat. But I don't know whether that refers to Shabbat in his time zone or in mine.

Comment: GotQuestions, I've edited your question to better comport to general guidelines on how to ask a good question. Please indicate whether it matches your intent; if not, [edit] it further; and then it can be reopened to answers. Please also note that Mi Yodeya makes no guarantee of validity, and does not offer professional (particularly rabbinic) advice. Treat information from this site like it came from a crowd of your friends and bring that info with you when consulting with your rabbi for practical ruling. I recommend you  take the site [tour] for a better understanding of how it works.

Comment: Oh! Now I see that this question [has already been asked and answered on this site](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/11839). You're in luck! Answers ready-made for you.

Comment: The link you provided does not address this question directly.  It contains one source that can answer this question.  I am looking for more sources.  Regarding you amendment to my question, "I know there's a general rule against asking a non-Jew to perform ... But I don't know whether that refers to Shabbat in his time zone or in mine. "  I know it is for certain asur in my time zone.  Again the question is whether it is asur in a different time zone when a goy is doing it also for his own benefit.  This is a question tackled by many moderm poskim.  I just need the sources.

Comment: If the answers now there are inadequate, see http://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers