# Talking on the phone when it's shabbos for the other person

Tags: shabbat, lifnei-iver

I am  not religious, but I have relatives who are. I live in the US and some of my relatives live in Israel.
Can they talk to me when it is after shabbos in Israel, but it's still shabbos in the US?

They would not be causing me to violate shabbos, I never keep it anyways. I really want to talk to them, and it's hard to find a time to do so because of the time difference.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya! Can you [edit] your question to make it less personal? We [try to avoid practical halachic questions](//meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1734). You might also want to see "[Why is it necessary to ask a rabbi?](//judaism.stackexchange.com/q/9146)" for more info. We hope to see you around!

Comment: Also, you might want to look at some of these related questions: [Am I allowed to view a Kotel Cam on Shabbos?](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/11070/5151) and [BT emailing non-observant family on Friday afternoon](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/29369/5151).

Answer (score 2):

You are Jewish and even if you are not religious, the laws of Judaism are still relevant to you although you do not keep them. See [this article entitled Is a Jew Who Converts Still Jewish?](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1269075/jewish/Is-a-Jew-Who-Converts-Still-Jewish.htm) The last part reads:

> once you are a part of this people, you are the entire people. As
>   Israel is eternal, so your bond with them is irreversible, unbreakable
>   and eternal.

So your  religious relatives will not want to  talk to you when it is after shabbos in Israel, but it's still shabbos in the US.

Comment: Like I said. I would be violating shabbos regardless. Just like I'm doing now while I'm commenting.