# Could a person leave skype on all shabbat?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, technology, internet

I am wondering if it's forbidden to leave a skype call on all day/night during shabbat if a person prepared the skype call BEFORE shabbat and if it was only a ***voice call*** and not a video call and if the person didn't touch the computer at all during shabbat
(what if the person talked about Torah during the call to keep in the spirit of shabbat?)

Comment: I don't see how this is a duplicate. The earlier question is about a video call, possibly also including audio, whereas this is about an audio call. cc @DoubleAA

Comment: Sort of related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/56172/5323